# How to update a XML node, using a trigger in Oracle (XMLELEMENT)

Tags: oracle, triggers

I just start to write a trigger in oracle. And this trigger need to modify a node into a xml using the xmlements in Orecle

**This is the trigger:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_news_name
    after insert on SelectiveProcess
for each ROW
declare
  v_new_name  VARCHAR2(400);
  v_data         xmltype;
BEGIN
       v_data := :new.dataNode;
       SELECT  to_char(ExtractValue(v_data ,'/DATAS/NEWS_NAME'))
              INTO
              v_new_name  
       FROM DUAL;

       v_new_name  := :new.codigo || ' - ' || v_new_name ;

       [.........]

end;
```

Now I need to update the node **NEWS_NAME** using the variable **v_new_name**.

I know I can update a node using a simple query like this follow exemple:

```
UPDATE SelectiveProcess SET dataNode =
   UPDATEXML(dataNode,
   '/DATAS/NEWS_NAME','TESTE NAME')
   WHERE ID = 3;
```

But how to do that in a trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AFTER INSERT` Triggers do not allow you to update the `:NEW` values.
So, basically convert it to a `BEFORE INSERT` and override the `:NEW` value as you do it in an update statement.

```
 select   UPDATEXML(dataNode,
       '/DATAS/NEWS_NAME', v_new_name ) INTO :new.dataNode  FROM DUAL;
```

Or putting it all together.

```
 SELECT  UPDATEXML(dataNode,
       '/DATAS/NEWS_NAME', :new.codigo || ' - ' 
     to_char(ExtractValue(:new.dataNode ,'/DATAS/NEWS_NAME') ) ) INTO  :new.dataNode FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I am receiving this mensage:  PLS-00201: identifier 'UPDATEXML' must be declared

Comment: @DaviAmaral : It seems the function can't be used in PL/sql scope. updated the answer now.

Comment: My fault ... I used the second  option and now is working... tks!